# NPM module not found grunt sass

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, npm-install

> Local Npm module "grunt-sass" not found. Is it installed?

Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task

> 0 paths cleaned.

Running "generateConstantsFileWithConfig" task

Running "ngconstant:local" (ngconstant) task
Creating module config at app/res/config/config.js...OK

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task
Warning: Error: Cannot find where you keep your Bower packages. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Comment: It's strange but use "ipconfig /flushdns" command helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve any problem related with the npm module you could use:  —unsafe-perm

when you are installing that module or package. For example if you have problems when you install bowel and node you could use:

sudo  npm install --unsafe-perm && bower install —unsafe-perm

which solve the problem I had.